# Reading CPU model specific registers on linux

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 but testes it also on Debian. I have Intel **i5-5675C** processor. I am using **msr-tools-1.3** to do it. I am able to read register **0x00001a2** with the following command:

```
rdmsr 0x00001a2
```

It gives me some good output according to the datasheet. However I can't do anything handy with this value.

I would like to read some model-specific registers from my CPU associated with temperature or voltage or something useful. Datasheet info:

[Datasheet Vol 1](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/desktop-5th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html)

[Datasheet Vol 2](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/desktop-5th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-2.html)

From datasheet Vol 2:  **5.2.52 IA32-IA32_THERM_STATUS**,

```
 rdmsr 0x000059c0
 rdmsr: CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x000059c0
```

I get an error like this. I have tried running it on all 4 CPU cores and have enabled modprobe and files are present in **/dev/cpu/{CPU_ID}/msr**:

```
sudo modprobe msr
```

Here is strace output:

```
sudo strace rdmsr 0x59c0
execve("/usr/sbin/rdmsr", ["rdmsr", "0x59c0"], [/* 25 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x84d000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe87cb3f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92026, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 92026, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe87cb28000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\v\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1869392, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3972864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe87c554000
mprotect(0x7fe87c714000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe87c914000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7fe87c914000
mmap(0x7fe87c91a000, 16128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe87c91a000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe87cb27000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe87cb26000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe87cb25000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fe87cb26700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe87c914000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x602000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fe87cb41000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fe87cb28000, 92026)           = 0
open("/dev/cpu/0/msr", O_RDONLY)        = 3
pread(3, 0x7ffcd2bddf78, 8, 22976)      = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
write(2, "rdmsr: CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x0"..., 40rdmsr: CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x000059c0
) = 40
exit_group(4)                           = ?
+++ exited with 4 +++
```

Comment: What does `uname -r` show and what arguments are you passing to `rdmsr`?

Comment: There is no MSR 0x59c0. You cannot read what is not there.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the line:

```
pread(3, 0x7ffcd2bddf78, 8, 22976)      = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

where `22976 = 0x59c0`, which is the MSR address you are trying to read. The `EIO` error appears when in [msr_read](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/kernel/msr.c?h=v3.16#n68) function the call to [rdmsr_safe_on_cpu](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#n371) leading to [rdmsr_safe](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#n282) macro calling the [native_read_msr_safe](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#n137) function results in #GP exception on executing the `RDMSR` instruction.

So, your CPU doesn't support the MSR you're trying to read.

But, as pointed out in the [answer by duskwuff](https://superuser.com/a/1341729/87525), you're reading the wrong datasheet. The offset 0x59c0 is the offset relative to `MCHBAR`, which points to the *memory* space – it's not an address of any MSR. To find the correct MSR address you should read [Volume 3B of the Intel's manual – System Programming Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf), namely, its chapter 14.4. There it's said that `IA32_THERM_STATUS` (note, not `IA32—IA32_THERM_STATUS`) MSR has address 0x19c.

Comment: You are right, that means that the register doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have misread the datasheet.

`IA32—IA32_THERM_STATUS` is a configuration register in the platform PCI device, not a CPU MSR. It cannot be read using `rdmsr`.

Comment: That is wrong! You can of course read the IA32_THERM_STATUS (in most cases address 0x19c). But you have to load the msr kernel before.

Comment: @abu_bua Context is important. The OP was specifically referring to a register described in the datasheet with offset 59c0h; this register is part of the platform PCI device. It's on page 144 of https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/5th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-2.pdf

Comment: @abu_bua actually this is right, and it nicely complements my answer. `IA32—IA32_THERM_STATUS` is at `MCHBAR+0x59c0` in the _memory_ space. Although it's indeed possible to read `IA32_THERM_STATUS` via the MSR interface at address 0x19c, the offset 0x59c0 found by the OP is related to MMIO, not MSRs. So definitely, the OP has misunderstood the datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, I missread the op' question!

Answer (score 0):

Two things jump out

`open("/dev/cpu/0/msr", O_RDONLY)        = 3`

Open passed returning the file descriptor with value 3

The `msr registers` can only be read/written with Root. [The man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/msr.4.html) makes this clear.

SUDO used to stand for **S**uper**U**ser **DO**. On modern Linux is more like **S**ubstitute **U**ser **DO**. SUDO doesn't mean the user executing the task is necessarily Root. Often it temporarily elevates a user's status to do things things *as* that user. So while you *may* have root permissions you *can* still fail the `UserID == 0` check.

Try the same command in a root shell and see if it fails.

Comment: If the problem were with permissions, you'd fail to open the file. The actual problem happens later, on `pread`, which returns `EIO`.